# How do I change the PayPal items array to each order?

Tags: javascript, html, paypal

I have the following JavaScript that loads the PayPal buttons on my website and i need to alter this code so that the items that were added into the shopping cart are in the PayPal invoice as well:

```js
<script src="cart.js"></script>

    <script>
        paypal.Buttons({
            createOrder: function(data, actions) {
                // This function sets up the details of the transaction, including the amount and line item details.
                return actions.order.create({
                    purchase_units: [{
                        amount: {
                            value: countCartTotal()
                        }
                    }]
                });
            },
            onApprove: function(data, actions) {
                // This function captures the funds from the transaction.
                return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
                    // This function shows a transaction success message to your buyer.
                    window.location.href = "orderConfirmed.php"
                    clearCart()
                });
            }
        }).render('#paypal-button-container');
        //This function displays Smart Payment Buttons on your web page.
    </script>
```

It is loaded at the bottom of my webpage, the 'cart.js' holds the value of the entire cart, e.g. if the total amount it $20.00 the user will be charged $20.00 in the PayPal window. I have tested this code in the Sandbox environment from PayPal and it works. But it doesn't give me the items in the cart.

I got the code below from a user on here:

```js
"purchase_units": [{
      "description": "Stuff",
      "amount": {
        "value": "20.00",
        "currency_code": "USD",
        "breakdown": {
          "item_total": {
            "currency_code": "USD",
            "value": "20.00"
          },
        }
      },
      "items": [
        {
          "unit_amount": {
            "currency_code": "USD",
            "value": "10.00"
          },
          "quantity": "1",
          "name": "Item 1",
        },
        {
          "unit_amount": {
            "currency_code": "USD",
            "value": "10.00"
          },
          "quantity": "1",
          "name": "Item 2",
        },
      ],
    }
  ]
```

So I insert it into my script file so that it looks like this:

```js
 <script src="cart.js"></script>

    <script>
        paypal.Buttons({
            createOrder: function(data, actions) {
                // This function sets up the details of the transaction, including the amount and line item details.
                return actions.order.create({
                    "purchase_units": [{
                        "description": "Stuff",
                        "amount": {
                            "value": "20.00",
                            "currency_code": "USD",
                            "breakdown": {
                                "item_total": {
                                    "currency_code": "USD",
                                    "value": "20.00"
                                },
                            }
                        },
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "unit_amount": {
                                    "currency_code": "USD",
                                    "value": "10.00"
                                },
                                "quantity": "1",
                                "name": "Item 1",
                            },
                            {
                                "unit_amount": {
                                    "currency_code": "USD",
                                    "value": "10.00"
                                },
                                "quantity": "1",
                                "name": "Item 2",
                            },
                        ],
                    }
                    ]
                });
            },
            onApprove: function(data, actions) {
                // This function captures the funds from the transaction.
                return actions.order.capture().then(function(details) {
                    // This function shows a transaction success message to your buyer.
                    window.location.href = "orderConfirmed.php"
                    clearCart()
                });
            }
        }).render('#paypal-button-container');
        //This function displays Smart Payment Buttons on your web page.
    </script>
```

And this work for the data entered but I need the data entered to change based on whatever order is submitted. An example of an item is:

```html
<div class="mm-quarter">
    <img class="product__image" src="images/image.jpg" alt="Product" style="width:100%">
    <h2 class="product__name">Mobile Trigger Attachments</h2>
    <h3 class="product__price">10.00</h3>
    <button class="btn btn--primary" data-action="ADD_TO_CART">Add To Cart</button>
</div>
```

In 'cart.js', I reference the product name, price & quanity using these few lines:

```js
addToCartButtonsDOM.forEach(addToCartButtonDOM => {
    const productDOM = addToCartButtonDOM.parentNode;

    // this function get the name of the item for the cart
    if (productDOM.querySelector('.product__name').innerText === product.name) {
        handleActionButtons(addToCartButtonDOM, product);
    }
});


// this function gets the name, image, price, and quantity
addToCartButtonsDOM.forEach(addToCartButtonDOM => {
    addToCartButtonDOM.addEventListener('click', () => {
        const productDOM = addToCartButtonDOM.parentNode;
        const product = {
            image: productDOM.querySelector('.product__image').getAttribute('src'),
            name: productDOM.querySelector('.product__name').innerText,
            price: productDOM.querySelector('.product__price').innerText,
            quantity: 1,
        };

        const isInCart = (cart.filter(cartItem => (cartItem.name === product.name)).length > 0);

        if (!isInCart) {
            insertItemToDOM(product);
            cart.push(product);
            saveCart();
            handleActionButtons(addToCartButtonDOM, product);
        }
    });
});
```

Also when I add in the `countCartTotal()` to both "value:" it stops working?

The user that gave me the answer said it was straight forward JS, but I have limited knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Also when I add in the countCartTotal() to both "value:" it stops working?

Since you are using an itemized breakdown, there are those 2 values plus as many values as you have items. You will need to calculate and update the value of everything, and they *must* add up mathematically. If you change the total without making the items add up to the total, it will indeed stop working.

The approach I would suggest is to create a new function, `getPurchaseUnits()` or similar.

This should return an array much like the `purchase_units` you have hardcoded, but with the items and correct totals all updated. Writing this type of code requires some level of programming knowledge, of course, so you can take it as an opportunity to learn some Javascript -- much like a homework problem.

Once you have such a function that returns the array you need, you can place it inside,

```
return actions.order.create({
    getPurchaseUnits()
});
```